# Check if multiple textfields are empty - iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So, I'm developing an app signUp screen. I'm trying to check each field on the signUp screen to see if it's empty, and if it is, display an error message in a label to the user. I've been using a chain of else-ifs

```
    if ((self.firstNameField.text?.isEmpty) != nil) {
        errorLabel.text = "first name missing"
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }

    else if ((self.lastNameField.text?.isEmpty) != nil) {
        errorLabel.text = "last name missing"
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }

    else if ((self.emailField.text?.isEmpty) != nil) {
        errorLabel.text = "email missing"
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }

    else if ((self.passwordField.text?.isEmpty) != nil) {
        errorLabel.text = "password missing"
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }

    else if ((self.confirmPasswordField.text?.isEmpty) != nil) {
        errorLabel.text = "password confirmation missing"
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    }

    else if (self.passwordField.text != self.confirmPasswordField.text) {
        errorLabel.text = "Passwords don't match, try again!"
        errorLabel.hidden = false
    } 
    //omitted what happens if there are no fields missing
```

Now, when I run the application with all the textfields empty, the errorLabel displays the message "first name missing". Putting in a first name and pressing the signup button does nothing. I want it to change to "last name missing", but it stays at "first name missing".

Comment: So you believe that `(self.firstNameField.text?.isEmpty) != nil` will somehow be false????

Comment: Where do you call this validation code? It should be consistently called whenever you change any of the text fields or tap signup

Comment: In Swift 2 I would do: if firstNameField.text.character.count == 0 { ..

Comment: Also: have you heard about loops?

Answer (score 10):

The reason this is happening is because you are checking if `self.field.text?.isEmpty != nil`. You should be checking for `(self.field.text?.isEmpty ?? true)`

Essentially, you're trying to get the text in the field, and if there is no text, then `nil` is returned. By using `field.text?`, you are making the next variable you access nil based on whether `field.text` is nil. So, when there is no text, `field.text == nil`, doing `field.text?.isEmpty` will always return nil.

When there is text, `field.text?.isEmpty` will not be nil, and will always be false, but `nil != false`, so the statement will always return `false`.

To fix this, you should check

```
if(self.field.text?.isEmpty ?? true)
```

which essentially means

```
if((self.field.text?.isEmpty == nil ? true : self.field.text?.isEmpty))
```

Basically, this will return true if `field.text == nil` (which would make `field.text?.isEmpty` nil, making the result `true` due to the `??` operator), and will also return true if `field.text != nil || field.text.isEmpty`. It will only return false if `self.field.text != nil && !self.field.text.isEmpty`.

Another way to write this statement would be

```
if(self.field.text == nil || self.field.text!.isEmpty)
```

Comment: No problem! If you want to mark this answer as the correct one, you can click the check mark under the vote count

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
if self.firstNameField.text?.isEmpty {
     errorLabel.text = "first name missing"
     errorLabel.hidden = false
}

else if self.lastNameField.text?.isEmpty {
    errorLabel.text = "last name missing"
    errorLabel.hidden = false
}

else if self.emailField.text?.isEmpty {
    errorLabel.text = "email missing"
    errorLabel.hidden = false
}

else if self.passwordField.text?.isEmpty {
    errorLabel.text = "password missing"
    errorLabel.hidden = false
}

else if self.confirmPasswordField.text?.isEmpty {
    errorLabel.text = "password confirmation missing"
    errorLabel.hidden = false
}

else if (self.passwordField.text != self.confirmPasswordField.text) {
    errorLabel.text = "Passwords don't match, try again!"
    errorLabel.hidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try this out:

```
if self.firstNameField.text! == "" {
   errorLabel.text = "first name missing"
   errorLabel.hidden = false
}
else if self.lastNameField.text! == "" {
  errorLabel.text = "last name missing"
  errorLabel.hidden = false
}
 else if self.emailField.text! == "" {
  errorLabel.text = "email missing"
  errorLabel.hidden = false
}
 else if self.passwordField.text! == "" {
   errorLabel.text = "password missing"
   errorLabel.hidden = false
}
 else if self.confirmPasswordField.text! == "" {
  errorLabel.text = "password confirmation missing"
  errorLabel.hidden = false
}
 else if !(self.passwordField.text! == self.confirmPasswordField.text!) {
  errorLabel.text = "Passwords don't match, try again!"
  errorLabel.hidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid if-else cases and achieve it with one line code with ternary conditional operators in swift.

```
firstNameField.text?.isEmpty == true ? showError(message: ""first name missing"") : isValid()
...
}

func showError(message : String){
 errorLabel.text = message
 errorLabel.hidden = false
}
func isValid(){
  // hide label or anything else you want
}
```